# Does proc reduce runtime in tcl?

Tags: runtime, tcl

I think that is a good point to know.
proc will help to make our code more clear but makes it the run faster ?

Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Event if using procedures (read: structuring the code) would hurt performance, that wouldn't be a reason not to use procedures (read: to write unstructured code).

Comment: Procedures: clearer _and_ faster. What's not to like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally with more than one invocation yes, as procs a compiled to bytecode on their first invocation, so they are only parsed once. From the second invocation onward the bytecode is just executed  cf. http://wiki.tcl.tk/1677 for more technical details.

Comment: Its worth noting, just for context, that commands in the global scope (not in a proc) are not byte compiled. The process of byte compiling code does take time and, since global scope code is generally assumed to only run once, the interp doesn't bother to compile it. This is also the reason that running the process more than once is mentioned; the first time it is run will be slower, but each additional call will be faster.